# Composition of operators in $w_{1+\infty}$ and $W_{1+\infty}$

Tags: lie-algebras, mp.mathematical-physics, vertex-algebras, w-algebras

The algebra $W_{1+\infty}$ can be defined as a central extension of the lie algebra $w_{1+\infty}$ (defined as being spanned by $\left(-\partial_z \right)^m z^{-k}$ ). See for example: [Alexandrov, arxiv:1412.3772v4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.3772v4.pdf).

With any operator $a\in w_{1+\infty}$ we identify an operator $\widehat{Y}_a\in W_{1+\infty}$ 
\begin{equation}
\widehat{Y}_{\left(-\partial_z \right)^m z^{-k}}=\mbox{res}_z\left(z^{-k}: \frac{(\widehat{J}(z)+\partial_z)^{m}}{m+1} \widehat{J}(z):\right)
\end{equation}
where $\widehat{J}(z)$ is the bosonic current
\begin{align}
\widehat{J}(z)= \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{\widehat{J}_m}{z^{m+1}},
\end{align}
with modes
\begin{align}
\widehat{J}_k =
\begin{cases}
\displaystyle{\frac{\partial}{\partial t_k} \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \mathrm{for} \quad k>0},\\[10pt]
\displaystyle{0}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \mathrm{for} \quad k=0,\\[10pt]
\displaystyle{-kt_{-k} \,\,\,\,\,\mathrm{for} \quad k<0.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and the normal ordering $:\dots:$ puts all operators $\widehat{J}_k$ with positive $k$ to the right of all $\widehat{J}_k$ with negative $k$.

**Question:** 
Let $a,b \in w_{1+\infty}$, and $a \circ b$ be the composition of the differential operators. Then is there a definite relation between $\widehat{Y}_{a \circ b}$ and $\widehat{Y}_{a}, \widehat{Y}_{b}$? Can one write down a formula to obtain $\widehat{Y}_{a \circ b}$ from $\widehat{Y}_{a}$ and $\widehat{Y}_{b}$?